# NameError: global name 'Ui_DiabeticRetinopathy3' is not defined

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4

I am working on an multiform application where I am able to link the (form1 to form2 and form3), (form2 to form3) but when I am trying to create a link from (form2 to form1) and from3 to (form2 or form1) link to the backward page it is giving me the error `NameError: global name is not defined`.

Here is my calling methods code where form3 can call form4 but form4 does not call form3;

**Code : form3.py**

```
class Ui_DiabeticRetinopathy3(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(Ui_DiabeticRetinopathy3, self).__init__(parent)
        self.imgPreProc = imagePreProcessor()
        #self.imgPreProc = imagePreProcessor()
        self.setupUi(self)

    def setupUi(self, DiabeticRetinopathy):
        DiabeticRetinopathy.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("DiabeticRetinopathy"))
        DiabeticRetinopathy.resize(672, 608)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8("../im0003.jpg")), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        DiabeticRetinopathy.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.pushButton_6 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
        self.pushButton_6.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("background-color: rgb(191, 191, 191);\n"
"font: 75 8pt \"Verdana\";"))
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_6"))
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_6)
        self.pushButton_6.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked_hemo)

    def on_clicked_hemo(self):
        self.obj4=Ui_DiabeticRetinopathy4(self)
        self.obj4.show()
```

**Code : form4.py**

```
class Ui_DiabeticRetinopathy4(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(Ui_DiabeticRetinopathy4, self).__init__(parent)
        self.imgPreProc = imagePreProcessor()
        #self.obj3=Ui_DiabeticRetinopathy3()
        #self.imgPreProc = imagePreProcessor()
        self.setupUi(self)

    def setupUi(self, DiabeticRetinopathy):
        DiabeticRetinopathy.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("DiabeticRetinopathy"))
        DiabeticRetinopathy.resize(672, 608)
        DiabeticRetinopathy.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.pushButton_6 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget) 
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_6"))
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_6)
        #self.pushButton_6.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked_micro)#####

    def on_clicked_micro(self):
        self.obj3=Ui_DiabeticRetinopathy3(self)
        #self.obj3.setupUi(self)
        self.obj3.show()
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you should show where these variables are created... also, it looks weird that in one you use `Ui_DiabeticRetinopathy4` and in the other function you use `Ui_DiabeticRetinopathy3`. And again, where are these variables created?

Comment: Please give more information of Ui_DiabeticRetinopathy4, Ui_DiabeticRetinopathy3. (what is your class inheritance ?) Thanks

Comment: i have added the code to make the idea clear..i  was actually trying to put less code to create less mess but i missed the important contents in that, that need to be focused.

Comment: @KitsuneMeyoko..these are two forms in two different files.. i am creating the object of form4 in form3 to call it(it works) but when i am creating the object of form3 in form4 it is giving this error"NameError: global name 'Ui_DiabeticRetinopathy3' is not defined" and i have also imported the form class in respective classes.

Answer (score 0):

> NameError: name 'Ui_DiabeticRetinopathy3' is not defined

If it possibility, please check your import module. Have you import `form3.py` into `form4.py`?

In `form4.py`, It should be possibility like this in head;

```
from form3 import *
from form3 import Ui_DiabeticRetinopathy3
```

Comment: thanks for ur response. the import was fine.i had made the changes in gui file..i have seperated the gui code from rest and passed the respective gui class to that new class and got my error resolved.